# How to implement search feature with SearchView, Retrofit and RxJava (RxBindings)?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-binding

When the  user types into the `SearchView` widget, the app should make an
API call (**in background thread**) to fetch search results from server, and display them (**in UI thread**) in RecyclerView.

I use the following code in my fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_fragment, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
                .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .switchMap(query -> retrofitService.search(query))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Item> items) {
                        // adapter.addItems(...)
                    }
                });
}
```

But I get an exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from the main thread. Was: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.internal.Preconditions.checkUiThread(Preconditions.java:35)
at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.SearchViewQueryTextChangesOnSubscribe.call(SearchViewQueryTextChangesOnSubscribe.java:18)
at com.jakewharton.rxbinding.support.v7.widget.SearchViewQueryTextChangesOnSubscribe.call(SearchViewQueryTextChangesOnSubscribe.java:10)
...
```

When I remove `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, the search API call is fired when fragment is created and no query is typed in `SearchView` and I get exeption

```java
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 422
```

then, when I type my search query `retrofitService.search(query)` is no longer called.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remember that you can actually use multiple `observeOn` and multiple `subscribeOn` operators in your rx chain.

Try this:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .switchMap(query -> retrofitService.search(query))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Item> items) {
                    // adapter.addItems(...)
                }
            });
```

This will basically result in this Thread usage:

[image: thread usage]

Comment: Otherwise you can specify Io thread when configuring Retrofit --   .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create(Schedulers.io))

Comment: yep, and then `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` would be unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

I use such an approach on a production app.

```
 RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
                    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(String text) throws Exception {
                            if (text.isEmpty()) {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .switchMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<String> apply(String query) throws Exception {
                            return dataFromNetwork(query);
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(String result) throws Exception {
                            textViewResult.setText(result);
                        }
                    });
```

- DistinctUntilChanged: The distinctUntilChanged operator is used to
  avoid the duplicate network calls. Let say the last on-going search
  query was “abc” and the user deleted “c” and again typed “c”. So
  again it’s “abc”. So if the network call is already going on with the
  search query “abc”, it will not make the duplicate call again with
  the search query “abc”. So, distinctUntilChanged suppress duplicate
  consecutive items emitted by the source Observable.
- SwitchMap: Here, the switchMap operator is used to avoid the network
  call results which are not needed more for displaying to the user.
  Let say the last search query was “ab” and there is an ongoing
  network call for “ab” and the user typed “abc”. Then you are no more
  interested in the result of “ab”. You are only interested in the
  result of “abc”. So, the switchMap comes to the rescue. It only
  provides the result for the last search query(most recent) and
  ignores the rest.

Comment: Hi, Can you share your dataFromNetwork() code? How can I fetch it from my ViewModel, using retrofit and Livedata?