# RxSearchView search

Tags: android, rx-java2

My question is two fold. I had been using `RxSearchView` for a while. I have used `map`, `filter` and finally `switchMap` to query the search events from api. First in the `map` or `filter` function, I have updated the ui like this:

```
.filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(String s) throws Exception {
                            if (searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString().length() < 3 && mUserList != null) {
                                mUserList.clear();
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mUserSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                            return s.length() > 2;
                        }
                    })
```

So is it a good practice to keep updating the ui from inside these functions ?
Secondly, deleting characters couldn't be handled this way. Please give me suggestions/ links. I am new to Rx. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> So is it a good practice to keep updating the ui from inside these functions ?

You do not need to and should not use `runOnUIThread()` here. You can add multiple calls to `observeOn` operators within your reactive chain to switch threads. Here are some links on threading :

- [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html) : Read about threading
- [`observeOn` and `subscribeOn`](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.in/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html) : The subscribeOn and observeOn gifs on the blog make it easier to visualize the difference and use
- [Common RxJava mistakes talk by Dan Lew](https://youtu.be/QdmkXL7XikQ?t=1493): We can use `observeOn` multiple times.
- [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575761/2854478) : Similar to what you need to achieve.

> Secondly, deleting characters couldn't be handled this way. Please give me suggestions/ links.

Instead of filtering you should instead use `debounce()` operator. 
Here's a [link to my talk](https://slideslive.com/38900615/rxify-a-simple-spell-for-complex-rxjava-operators) at Droidcon Boston, 2017 in which I talk about auto-search problem with `debounce()` and `switchMap()` Scroll to ~ 25:00 time. You can find the [demo code](http://github.com/ragdroid/rxify) which handles deletion of characters as well and also the [blog post](https://medium.com/fueled-android/rxify-maintaining-order-in-auto-complete-search-d5c46ba26578).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is of great help. Appreciate for your guidance. I will for sure take a look at your Droidcon talk :)